# Finding top 25 % customers for each group using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I have a following temp table **Customer**

```
   Customer      Group     Price
     A           Sales     100
     B           Lease     200
     C           Lease     300
     D           Lease     50
     E           Lease     100
     F           Sales     750
     G           Sales     200
     H           Lease     50
     I           Sales     130
     J           Lease     100
     K           Lease     200
     L           Sales     500
     M           Sales     1000
     N           Sales     10
     O           Sales     100
```

I want to find top 25 % customers for each **Group**.

For eq: *Sales* has total of 8 customers, so top 25 % would be 2. Hence i need top 2 customers for *Sales* who have highest **Price**.

Similarly, for *Lease*, i have total of 7 customers, top 25 % would be 1.75 which is ~2.

If there is a **Customer**, which has same **Price**, **Customer** which is higher in sorting can be chosen. For eq: **Customer** B and K have same **Price** of 200, hence B should be selected.

Here is the desired output:

```
  Customer      Group     Price
     B           Lease     200
     C           Lease     300
     F           Sales     750
     M           Sales     1000
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Have you done anything???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008, you can use:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by group order by price desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by group) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 0.25 * cnt;
```

Or, use apply:

```
select t.*
from (select distinct group from t) g cross apply
     (select top (25) percent t.*
      from t
      order by price desc
     ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select customer, grp, price
from (
    select t.*, percent_rank() over(partition by grp order by price desc, customer desc) prn
    from mytable t
) t
where prn < 0.25
order by grp, price
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=5aa3f20e5f6f564dce46ab8e4157d934)**:

```
customer | grp   | price
:------- | :---- | ----:
K        | Lease |   200
C        | Lease |   300
F        | Sales |   750
M        | Sales |  1000
```

---

**Edit**:

I am usunre that `percent_rank()` is available in SQL Server 2008, that you tagged your question with (as far as concerned it was introduced in version 2012). We can emulate it as follows:

```
select customer, grp, price
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        1.0 
            * rank() over(partition by grp order by price desc, customer desc) 
            / count(*) over(partition by grp) prn
    from mytable t
) t
where prn < 0.25
order by grp, price
```